# How does Bane of the Stricken work?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there a cap on stacks and/or total increased damage taken? Could, say, a barely 70 monk wale away on a T4 blue for 15 minutes and continue to stack with each hit?

Are stacks additive or multiplicative with each other? How do they stack from multiple Nelphalem using BoS, or other abilities that increase damage taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/3k30ej/an_indepth_guide_to_bane_of_the_stricken/):

> The base effect of the gem is multiplicative with other buffs but stacks additively with itself. There is no cap on this buff.

This is reiterated on the [Diablo Wikia page](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Bane_of_the_Stricken) also.

Comment: This is correct as far as I know. I also recall there being a _bug_ (?) where stricken stacks stacked between players during the PTR testing. Not sure if this is still the case.